# rightclick panel is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
                if (cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.panel3.BackColor = cd.Color;
                }
            }
        }

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
            if (pnl != null)
                pnl.DoDragDrop(pnl.BackColor, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }


    private void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Color));

        if (data != null)
            ((Panel)sender).BackColor = (Color)data;
    }

    private void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```

i want if i press right click on panel1 it should be shown color dialog for color selection,then i can drag panel1 color drop to on panel2.
but after this code colpetion finally drag and drop worked but not worked panel1 right click
help me ?

Answer (score 0):

In Mouse right click first invoke `mouse down` event so its not invoke `mouse click` event so you tried like this in mouse down event

```
 private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button !=MouseButtons.Right)
            {

            Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
            if (pnl != null)
                pnl.DoDragDrop(pnl.BackColor, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i change to mouse down event but not solved and not fired right click